# Rails testing render action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a dynamically driven Rails application where views and determined by the path requested.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  get ':tenant', to: 'tenants#home'
  get  '/:path', to: 'tenants#page', :constraints => { :path => /.*/ }
end
```

TenantsController:

```
class TenantsController < ApplicationController
    def home
        render :template => params[:tenant] + "/home"
    end

    def page
        render :template => params[:path]
    end
end
```

As you can see what simply happens is we get the path constraint from the endpoint and render a view template from it.

I would like to write a test that ensures rails requests a view template that matches the URL requested. (Basically test the page method within TenantsController).

Given that I do not want to tie my test into tenants that may be in the system, how can I write a test for this generically without the test knowing about some Tennant?

Answer (score 0):

You can write tests for your controller using the [assert_template](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TemplateAssertions/assert_template) method:

```
test "should render the correct template" do
  ['path1', 'path2'].each do |path|
    get '/', params: { path: path }
    assert_template "#{path}"
  end
end
```

[This guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers) provides more details on how to test your controllers.